# Prevent same action called twice as long as user is in current session

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, double-submit-problem

I am using Struts2 framework, my problem is

If user log-in into system and clicked some action lets say `ACTION1`, flow will go to action class and executes some method, return appropriate result.
He may visit some of the web pages, and again clicked `ACTION1`.

As long as he is in the same session, now the control should not go that particular method but the result should be same as previous results.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Right away go to the same method but result could be different, it depends on the value returned by the action.

Comment: I don't want method to be called again... is it possible?

Comment: It depends on how do you control the user session?

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your reply,
can you please tell me in detail how to do it? I am new to Struts

Comment: you mean to cache the response & prevent action execution ? I don't suggest doing this for any actions. Although static files will already be cached by your browser & you can set some level of action caching in your tomcat/apache/ngnix server

Comment: Could you tell what is a use case for such *feature*.

Comment: Actually its a client requirement, he don't want multiple requests calling the same method as long as the user is in the current session.
Can we achieve this? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can try a [`tokenSession` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/token-session-interceptor.html).

> This interceptor builds off of the [`token` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/token-interceptor.html), providing
> advanced logic for handling invalid tokens. Unlike the normal token
> interceptor, this interceptor will attempt to provide intelligent
> fail-over in the event of multiple requests using the same session.
> That is, it will block subsequent requests until the first request is
> complete, and then instead of returning the `invalid.token` code, it
> will attempt to display the same response that the original, valid
> action invocation would have displayed if no multiple requests were
> submitted in the first place.

It will prevent from double submit the same action or reuse the same token that you provide with [`s:token` tag](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/token-tag.html).

> **Description**
>
> Stop double-submission of forms.
>
> The token tag is used to help with the "double click" submission
> problem. It is needed if you are using the `TokenInterceptor` or the
> `TokenSessionInterceptor`. The `s:token` tag merely places a hidden
> element that contains the unique token.

Place the tag inside your form and you never get back in submitting the same form twice. Token session interceptor will try to handle invalid token for you by returning the same response like in first case.

Comment: I have already tried with tokenSession but its only working for Refresh, and double click